# Avada & WooCommerce Customization - Replacing product_title in woo-config.php

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have WooCommerce installed and I'm using Avada Theme and setup a child theme for my customizations. I tried to modify the `woo-config.php` file to the child theme, for my modifications, but Avada doesn't "read" the `woo-config.php` from the child theme. It probably wouldn't have been a good idea to customize `WooCommerce` by editing the `woo-config.php` anyhow.

But now I am left with a problem, how do I customize the WooCommerce pages? I tried a number of things without luck. I believe that I need to add a `remove_action` to my `functions.php`, removing Avada's addition, but I can't get it to work.

This is the code in the `woo-config.php` file that I'm trying to remove/edit:

```
/**
* Renders the product title.
*
* @access public
*/

public function product_title() {
    ?>
        <h3 class="product-title"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <div class="fusion-price-rating">
        <?php
    }
```

I tried adding a `remove_action` to my `functions.php` file in the child theme, but no luck. I'm pretty sure that I need to remove this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', array( $this, 'product_title' ), 10 );
```

And once it is removed, I can add my own add_action?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it took me a while, but this works:

```
function remove_avada_woocommerce_edits() {

    global $avada_woocommerce;
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', array( $avada_woocommerce, 'product_title' ), 10 );

}

add_action('init','remove_avada_woocommerce_edits');
```